# Can AngularJS Material Components work with Angular2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-material

I just received a web app project from a co-worker who left our company. The project was built using Angular2 as its framework but it appears as though this worker tried to use AngularJS Material for the HTML components.

From what I understand if I wanted a card component in AngularJS Material I would use the tag `<md-card>` and for Angular2 Material I would use the tag `<mat-card>`. In this project 100% of the components used are 'md' components which doesn't make sense for an Angular2 project.

When I serve the project nothing appears and I'm given the error: `'md-card' is not a known element.If 'md-card' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.` Which makes sense because 'md-card' shouldn't be a known element in Angular2.

So my question is: is it possible that you can get AngularJS Material components to work with Angular2 or will I have to rework all the HTML in the entire project?

Comment: Check this [angular-material-prefix-updater](https://npm.runkit.com/angular-material-prefix-updater)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to run both frameworks simultaneously to make it work. While that certainly is possible, it usually isn't desired, especially if there isn't a clear separation between where the AngularJS application and the Angular 2+ application ends and begins (for instance as there would be if you're migration an AngularJS application to Angular 4). AngularJS components, spread around an Angular 2+ application doesn't seem like a desirable situation.

Here are some additional issues:

- Component names may clash
- Routing may interfere with each other
- Communication between AngularJS components and Angular 2+ components is difficult

**I have two suggestions.**

1. Either do away with the AngularJS dependency and clean up after the former co-worker.
2. Or, create thin wrapper components around Angular2 Material components, that has the same name and signature as the AngularJS material components. This is only possible if the components work somewhat similarly.

I recommend the first suggestion, since the latter might only be plausible for the most simple components.